# Matlab: loading an indexed image

Tags: image, matlab, rgb, indexed

I'd like to read an image in matlab and convert it to an indexed image

Here is my code:

```
[I map] = imread('image.tif');
I = rgb2ind(I, map);

figure(1);
imagesc(I);axis('equal');
```

When I just read the image, it looks fine (but it is an rgb image). Then I convert it to an indexed image, I have the following picture:
[image]

What is wrong with this piece of code?

Comment: What's wrong with the image?

Comment: This is not the original image. The original image is a picture of a person.

Comment: Which is rather vital information to the question. You should add the original image.

Comment: This is a picture of me, so I don't want to post it. I'm assuring you it has nothing to do with the rainbow I you can see above. It isn't very colorful, rather dark (but is also isn't black and white).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is the result of a misuse of the matlab functions.

```
%read a non-indexed image. I is your RGB image, map is empty
[I,map] = imread('board.tif');
%rgb2ind has two output arguments, get both, otherwise your unchanged code
[I2,map2] = rgb2ind(I, map);
%Now I2 is a indexed image and map2 the corresponding map
```

Now you display your indexed image I2 without applying a colormap:

```
imagesc(I2)
```

Your image contains values 1:n and colormap `jet` is activated, so you get a rainbow.

Possibilities to display the correct image are using the map:

```
imagesc(I2)
colormap(map2)
```

Or displaying I, which is the original RGB image

```
imagesc(I)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is slightly off. This should work:

```
[I, map] = imread('autumn.tif');
[I, map] = rgb2ind(I, map);

figure(1);
image(I);
colormap(map);
axis('equal');
```

See documentation of [rgb2ind](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html?refresh=true).